# Adding "app:" attributes to a custom style in Android

Tags: android, android-styles

Attributes prefixed by "android" work fine, but how do I add the ones prefixed by something else?

For example, how can I add the following two attributes to the style bellow?

```
app:chipCornerRadius="20dp"
app:textStartPadding="8dp"

<style name="Chip" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/smallTextSize</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Just remove the `app:` prefix; e.g., `<item name="chipCornerRadius">...</item>`.

Comment: @MikeM. Using a style with the `app:` prefix removed does not work for the example above with `Chip`.

Comment: Then you've got some other issue. There is no other way to specify app-local attributes. Make sure you've got whichever library you're using added correctly, that you have the attribute names spelled correctly, and that you're using a version that actually offers those attributes.

Comment: @MikeM. It's about the `Chip` from the support library and the attributes are spelled correctly. The attributes work fine if I add them to a chip in my layout but will not work if I add them to a style and apply the style.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "will not work"? Are you getting a build error, or a runtime error?

Comment: Btw, your `parent` style is wrong. It should be one of the `Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.*` styles shown here: https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/.

Comment: I was using it all wrong when applying the style. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah, I kinda figured that was it, after I saw the `parent`. Sorry I didn't notice that right away. Glad you got it working. Cheers!